# Javascript : [ onmouseover ] and [ onmouseout ] event

Tags: javascript, events, onmouseover, onmouseout

### **The General Problem**

---

Imagine a dropdown menu for example and when you `mouse over` on a link the dropdown is popping up.

But as you can read on the article below, there are problems with it, when you mouse over on a link(for some browsers everything inside the element) the box is dissapearing. The problem comes from [`event bubbling`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html).

In my document `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` are `delayed with 0.5 seconds` and you can see that sometimes the element starts to vibrate, because of this problem.

```
--------------
| Layer      |.onmouseout = doSomething;
| --------   |
| | Link | ----> We want to know about this mouseout
| |      |   |
| --------   |
| --------   |
| | Link |   |
| |    ----> | but not about this one
| --------   |
--------------
---->: mouse movement
```

**Read this article for understanding better:**

**[www.quirksmode.org - Javascript - Mouse Events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#mouseover)**

### **Quirksmode solution**

---

```
function doSomething(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    var tg = (window.event) ? e.srcElement : e.target;
    if (tg.nodeName != 'DIV') return;
    var reltg = (e.relatedTarget) ? e.relatedTarget : e.toElement;
    while (reltg != tg && reltg.nodeName != 'BODY')
        reltg= reltg.parentNode
    if (reltg== tg) return;
    // Mouseout took place when mouse actually left layer
    // Handle event
}
```

### **My document**

---

You can find my full document here:

[JS Bin - My documents](http://jsbin.com/oqoho/3/edit)

You can find the original document without `mouseEvent(e)` function here:

[JS Bin - Original](http://jsbin.com/oqoho/4/)

*Mouseover on the button then mouse over the box then quickly mouseout and quickly come back to box then it will start to vibrate. (On Firefox 3.6 Windows 7)*

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mouseEvent(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    var tg = (window.event) ? e.srcElement : e.target;
    if (tg.nodeName != 'DIV') return;
    var reltg = (e.relatedTarget) ? e.relatedTarget : e.toElement;
    while (reltg != tg && reltg.nodeName != 'BODY')
        reltg= reltg.parentNode
    if (reltg== tg) return;
    // Mouseout took place when mouse actually left layer
    // Handle event
}
function toggleByType(id, type, e){
    setTimeout(function(){
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        if(element.style.display == type){
            mouseEvent(e);
            element.style.display = 'none'; 
        } else {
            element.style.display = type;   
        }
    }, 500);
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box-container" onmouseover="toggleByType('box','block');" onmouseout="toggleByType('box','block', event);">
    <a href="#" class="box-bridge">Show Box</a>
    <div id="box" class="box" style="display:none;">
            Mouse out and this will dissapear.
            <br />
            <a href="#">Roll over to have problems</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

### **My Problem**

---

**The solution what quirksmode is giving sounds logical however I don't know `how to use the function` I tried in a lots of ways what I posted is just one, but I don't get it, so I would be very happy if you could help me to make this work.**

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `event` in the `onmouseover` attribute:

```
onmouseover="toggleByType('box','block', event);"
```

But, you've still a 500ms delay before the menu shows up.

Comment: Well firstly I added event to `onmouseover` too but it's just not better :|.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using pure CSS? With the :hover meta-tag you can easily set-up this menu without using any JS. Works with all modern browsers (except pre-IE 7).

Example:

```
.box { display: none }; .box-container:hover .box { display: block }
```

Comment: I want to have that 0.5 second delay.